# qt/pyqt how to make spinbox-signal only for user action/event?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I need to react(make event) only to user action, but program has to be able to change value too, but without event.

If I use comboBox is there signal activated(int) for this reason. How can I do it for spin-box?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an activated for the spinbox because the only activation is to click on the button - which sends a change signal

You can always set the value of the spinbox with `spinBox->setValue(value)`;

edit: you want to set a spinbox without having it emit a signal ?
Best way is for the setter to temporarily disable signals from the control with [QObject::blockSignals()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#blockSignals)

Comment: `spinbox->setValue(value)` will cause `emit valueChanged(value)` which is the behavior the poster wants to avoid.

Comment: @tmpearce - ok I've changed the answer - if this what the OP means I will edit the question title

Comment: Yeah, `blockSignals()` is the only way I can think to do it, but it isn't pretty - it puts the burden on every caller, instead of being able to set a property within the widget, for example.

Comment: @tmpearce - you could always derive a new spin control, or have a setSilent() function that took a ptr to the control - but yes it's bad. Not as bad as MFC though, where you needed lots of extra flags variables to stop recursive set/update calls

Comment: @MartinBeckett:  actually don't see why its so "bad" to do what you suggest and subclass your own spinbox, creating a `setValueSilent()` method that blocks and unblocks signals. Seems very clean to me.

Comment: @jdi - because the toolkit really should have it. Everyone subclassing a control to add the same identical missing functionality is a sign of bad design in the class library.